# Unable to log when using functions.auth.user().onCreate compared to functions.https.onRequest event

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm facing an issue where **console.log()** or **functions.logger.log()** doesn't appear to work when used within the **functions.auth.user().onCreate()** function for the Firebase Auth user creation event.

I've tried logging using a HTTP trigger and it works fine and I can see the output but it's just when I use the log functions inside the onCreate() function that I don't see anything unless my code throws some error.

I know the onCreate function is being triggered because I can at least see that in the logs.

Below is the full js function code for both the auth onCreate event and HTTP event.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

**Firebase Auth onCreate Event Function Code**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions/v1')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.authUserOncreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    console.log("=== Console Log ===")
    functions.logger.log("=== Functions Logger Log ===")

    console.log(user)

    const db = admin.firestore()

    await db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email
    })

})
```

**HTTP Event Function Code**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions/v1')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.httpRequest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    console.log("Console Log Statement");
    functions.logger.log("First line of function!")

})
```

Here is the package.json that is used for both the functions.

**package.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^11.11.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "20"
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see the output of the **console.log()** or **functions.logger.log()** when the function is ran but no luck.

As mentioned I've tried with a HTTP event triggered function and it works fine so not sure why it wouldn't work for the Firebase auth onCreate event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. Turns out the function was not updating with the newest code changes in the source.

I found out I was using an out dated copy of the code when I went to the **Cloud Functions** console -> Selected my function -> clicked **Source** -> clicked **DOWNLOAD ZIP** and compared the contents of the zip file with my latest code.

The problem I had was that I was using Terraform to deploy the function and the zip file which contains the source code was correctly packaged and put into the bucket but the function that was referencing that zip was not picking up the fact the contents of the zip was different and therefore not deploying the new zip file.

Probably didn't help that the name of my zip was the same with each deployment. I just expected the **google_cloudfunctions_function** resource to automatically pick up it was referencing a new zip based off the hash but it doesn't.

In order to get around it I used the following lifecycle on my **google_cloudfunctions_function** resource to trigger a rebuild of the function based off the hash of the object in the bucket.

```
lifecycle {
 replace_triggered_by = [
   google_storage_bucket_object.auth_user_oncreate.detect_md5hash
 ]
}
```

Hopefully it helps someone in the future and saves them hours of troubleshooting!